# cross browser html5 offline data storage?

Tags: html, web, storage, local

I am currently looking to write a web app in HTML5. It is my first HTML5 web app.

The main feature of this app is its offline feature. When I mean offline, it will be something like C:\APP\index.html (for Windows ), and it will be the same thing for Mac. So with that said, I have been looking into LocalStorage, WebSQL, IndexedDB.

And I come to this conclusion that LocalStorage is not going to be good enough for the web app that I am going to write. The IndexedDB only for all the major browsers except safari. Safari (desktop & iOS) supports WebSQL not IndexedDB. And then I found out that WebSQL is not going to be supported.

So I am wondering if there is a "universal" solution to my dilemma? Or Should I have code IndexedDB and WebSQL so that it will work on all the browsers? Any suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Your app is the only thing that needs to be accessing the data it stores, right?  If so, data is data is data, and as long as you include everything you need to read, write to, and understand the information your data encodes, it doesn't matter one bit (no pun intended) what format you use to store it.  Whatever language you are using to create the app, it will have library functions that can manipulate stored data.

If worst comes to worst, you can always go with the lowest common denominator and use a raw binary or text file; those are the only true universal formats.

Comment: thank you for the feedback. I do understand your point. But I am not sure if I  want to to raw binary or text file. I am looking something that "universal" data storage so that whichever browser that the user choose to use, it will work. I have been thinking of using xml, but I would rather use sql. I am currently looking into indexedDB and unfortunately I may have to use WebSQL because of Safari.